# We need to Launch mobile devices calendar from flutter app icon ontap

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to launch the mobile devices calendar from an icon press in flutter? We incorporated url_launcher plugin and are able to launch the devices phone and text apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have url_launcher integrated then `calshow://` for iOS and `content://com.android.calendar/time/` for Android should work.

Comment: thanks! so would you suggest an if statement so both will work?

Comment: @SamCromer Yes, check this to see how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924474/how-do-you-detect-the-host-platform-from-dart-code

Comment: how i pass parameters?