# Ignore if flutter library not supported

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

In my flutter app i have imported the flutter `file_picker` library. However this library does not currently support flutter web. The library is not imperative to my apps use.

**THE MAIN QUESTION:** Is there any way to check whether a library imported is unsupported and then in which case I can remove parts of the UI and code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, but knowing the limitations of the library, you could simply add the logic yourself for not showing some widget, based on the host,  [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50744481/4868256).

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a given library has web support is available, head to https://pub.dev/ , paste the package name in the search bar and check whether
the result has a **web** label. If the library is not available for the web, you can search for an alternative and do some refactoring, but since Flutter 2 was released, the most popular libraries are supported.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the user is using a supported platform by excluding the ones which are not.

For example:

```
import 'dart:io'; //Required import

if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
    //Do some stuff with the file_picker library
} else {
    //Tell the user that his platform is not currently supported
}
```