# How to ascertain whether the Flutter web app is running on phone or PC?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to use different apps on PC and mobile, so what would be the best way to find out what the device is before loading the app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you detect the host platform from Dart code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924474/how-do-you-detect-the-host-platform-from-dart-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [`Platform` class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform-class.html) of of `dart:io`, which provides a few **static** properties that can help you determine the OS and therefore PC vs mobile.

The following return `bool`s that help you determine each OS

`isAndroid`,
`isFuchsia`,
`isIOS`,
`isLinux`,
`isMacOS`,
`isWindows`

Or you can use the `operatingSystem` property, which returns a `String` containing the OS.

Ex.

```dart
if(Platform.isWindows)
...
```

In general, if you see Android & iOS as the OS, you'll know it's mobile. If you see Linux, MacOS, or Windows, you'll know it's PC. And Fuchsia is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: On the web this does not work for me. I get the following error `Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem`

Comment: @DanielS. You cannot use `dart:io` in web libraries. You should be getting a linter warning about this. If you want to find this information in the web, you'll need to use a separate package or make it yourself.

Answer (score 9):

As `dart:io` is not supported on the web, another solution is to look at the user agent (warning: a user could fake this to load the mobile or desktop version anyway).

```dart
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

const appleType = "apple";
const androidType = "android";
const desktopType = "desktop";

String getSmartPhoneOrTablet() {
  final userAgent = html.window.navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase();
  // smartphone
  if( userAgent.contains("iphone"))  return appleType;
  if( userAgent.contains("android"))  return androidType;

  // tablet
  if( userAgent.contains("ipad")) return appleType;
  if( html.window.navigator.platform.toLowerCase().contains("macintel") && html.window.navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 ) return appleType;

  return desktopType;
}
```

Credit to:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41311#issuecomment-739854345

Comment: Please accept this answer instead, as `Platform` does not work in web apps! /// I think there is no problem with looking at the user agent, provided that you only rely on it for adapting the visual UI. If the user changes their user agent string, I think it's safe to assume that they would prefer (or at least expect) the app variant tailored to that user agent.

Answer (score 1):

**You can easily findout with this code**

```
bool isMobile = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 850;
bool isTablet = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 1100 &&
    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 850;
bool isDesktop = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 1100;
```