# Flutter: Is there any way of using a widget only on ios but not on android?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, padding, flutter-ios, flutter-android

So I have been trying to add some padding only on ios but not on andoid. Is there any way to check if I am in android or ios so I can implement this feature in my app. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: more details [on this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45924474/451944)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Platform.operatingSystem` from the io library.

The output is a string which is:

- "ios" for IOS
- "android" for Android

You can also use `Platform.isIOS` or `Platform.isAndroid` directly.