# How to know phone operating system IOS or android flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to know phone operating system if IOS or android in flutter app is running on it through:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    }
```

In order to set if condition after the operating system is detected. How can I control this? Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you detect the host platform from Dart code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924474/how-do-you-detect-the-host-platform-from-dart-code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // Android-specific code
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  // iOS-specific code
}
```

Check the docs:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform-class.html