# How to see what device is used?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I need to customize web app whether it is used on laptop or phone, found ios or android detection, so would it work if I just did:

```
if (android or ios) {return phone version} else {computer version} ?
```

**SOLUTION**
solutions below gave me an error, but this package helped me:

https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io

```
checkOS() {
    if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
      return PhoneVersion;
    } else {
      return ComputerVersion,
      );
    }
  }
```

or

```
log('os: ${Platform.operatingSystem}');
```

Comment: See if this can answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924474/how-do-you-detect-the-host-platform-from-dart-code

Answer (score 3):

You can use Platform class:

```
import 'dart:io';

bool isDesktop = (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isLinux);
bool isMobile = (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid);
```

also you can use kIsWeb:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

if (kIsWeb) {
   // HORIZONTAL LAYOUT
} else {
   // VERTICAL LAYOUT
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // Do Android case
} else {
  // Do other case
}
```

For retrieving more information about user's device, use packages like [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info).

Comment: I got an error 'Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem'

Comment: What platform do you use?

Comment: i use windows .

Comment: Are you still faced with this question?