# Platform.isIOS not workin on real iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, dart-io

I made a login with Apple on my login screen, and I made an if statement to check if the platform is iOS to show it in iOS devices.

The problem is when I run the app on the **iOS simulator** the button shows up, but when **I run the app on a real device the button does not show up.**

```
if (Platform.isIOS)
     _LoginWithAppleIdWidget()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50744481/10584330

Comment: My issue is why it is not working on a real iOS device but works on an iOS simulator.