# How do you detect the host platform from flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-platform-channel

For UI that should differ slightly on iOS and Android, ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45924474/15045793 as it is question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50744481/10202281

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
```

Now you can detect the platform by just doing

```
Platform.isIOS // for ios
Platform.isAndroid //for android
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
```

Now, you need to check whether you are on Web or Application.

```
if(kIsWeb) {
   Enter Web specific code here
} else {
   if(Platform.isIOS){
      Enter IOS specific code here.
   } else if (Platform.isAndroid){
      Enter Android specific code here.
   }
}
```

Platform has following options:

```
Platform.isAndroid
Platform.isFuchsia
Platform.isIOS
Platform.isLinux
Platform.isMacOS
Platform.isWindows
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // Android-specific code
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  // iOS-specific code
}
```