# How to get the current Platform (System) of the running machine?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My Flutter application supports multiple platforms (Android, IOS, Windows, Web), How can I know the current Platform by the code?

I need to change some variables and URLs according to the Platform!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To detect the current Platform (System):

You can use the built-in `Platform` from `dart:io` like the following:

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // Android-specific code
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  // iOS-specific code
}
```

As you can see, inside the `Platform` class there are a condition for each Platform, which are:

```
Platform.isAndroid
Platform.isFuchsia
Platform.isIOS
Platform.isLinux
Platform.isMacOS
Platform.isWindows
```

and for the Web, you can use the the constant `kIsWeb` from the `flutter/foundation` like the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

if (kIsWeb) {
  // running on the web!
}
```

---

References:

1. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50744481/11217945) in Stack Overflow.
2. Dart Platform class [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.0/dart-io/Platform-class.html).